# Special characters (-&+, etc) not working in SOLR Query

Tags: solr

I'm using "text_general" fieldType for searching in SOLR. While searching with special characters I'm not getting proper results and getting errors. I would like to use special characters like these:

1. `-`
2. `&`
3. `+`

## Query

1. `solr?q=Healing - Live`
2. `solr?q=Healing & Live`

## Error message

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect
>   (org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse '("Healing
>   \': Lexical error at line 1, column 8. Encountered:  after :
>   "\"Healing \").

## schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>               
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

<copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape your query since the dash is a special character in lucene queries. Have a look at the other characters that you should escape [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters), and [here](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html) if you want to know more about the lucene query syntax.

Your query would then look like this: `solr?q=Healing \- Live`

I don't know which language you are writing code with but if you are using Java solrj provides the [ClientUtils#escapeQueryChars](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#escapeQueryChars%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: Im using C# with solr. Its working fine for Healing \- Live but getting below error for Oot \& Aboot.      message org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'Oot \': Lexical error at line 1, column 6. Encountered: <EOF> after : ""

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'Oot \': Lexical error at line 1, column 6. Encountered: <EOF> after : "").

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to escape the single `&`. Looks like you don't, but I might be wrong. What you do need to escape is `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

On Solr search based on Solarium:

`app\code\local\Module\Solarium\controllers\AjaxController.php`

```
function suggestAction()
{

    //get comp from http://[MAGE-ROOT]/solarium/ajax/suggest/?q=comp
    $comp = $this->getRequest()->getParam('q',false);

    //remove special characters
    $special_characters = array('(',')','/','\','&','!','.','-','+');
    $comp = str_replace($special_characters,'',$comp);

    //save q param
    $this->getRequest()->setParam('q',$comp);

    //existing code
    ...............

}
```

Answer (score 1):

StandardTokenizerFactory is the problem you should use WhitespaceTokenizerFactory. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `AND OR NOT` instead of those special characters.

For example:

```
Healing NOT Live
Healing AND Live
Healing OR Live
```