# How to search in solr with special character

Tags: solr

I'm a newbie in solr and i would like to search with special character.

for example

```
id:123
data:it's

q=it'
```

then it will retain the result data:it's

thanks
Donquixote

Comment: Use the force, luke : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277609/search-in-solr-with-special-characters

Comment: I already seen that one but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Could you specify which method you use to make your query ? `SolrJ`, http via curl, sorl admin

Answer (score 1):

The special character `'` you have used in the query, `q=data:it'*` will give you the result.

But there are some special characters like `~^*(){}[]:\"` and `white space`. For them you have to use **escape character** `\` during query. Other special characters, available in keyboard can be searched as is.